# How to require jQuery.loadTemplate using browserify

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp, browserify

I have setup browserify with Gulp.

When I require jQuery, everything works:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
```

When I try to require jquery load template module

```
var loadTemplate = require('jquery.loadtemplate')
```

I get an error

> module "jquery.loadtemplate " not found

I installed loadtemplate using `npm` like this

```
npm install --save jquery.loadtemplate
```

Comment: Depending on the error message, i think that it was installed at the wrong path... Did you install it into `node_modules`? There should be a folder `jquery.loadtemplate`.

Comment: @marcel yes I did install it in `node_module` (same place as jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

I think there is an error in the package.json of the jquery.loadtemplate module. It should define the source of the plugin somewhere and it's missing. In other modules the source is defined in the "main" property. It should say something like

"main": "jquery-loadTemplate/jquery.loadTemplate-1.5.0.js",

depending on the location of the script file. You can change it manually, but then it'll be deleted the next time you update/reinstall your npm package.